# How to apply s curve transform on gray scale image

Tags: matlab

I need a code example for s-curve transform to enhance the mammogram image. I'm struggling with its implementation. Kindly help

Comment: Hi Anushka, welcome to SO! What have you managed to accomplish so far, and what specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: I have performed histogram equalization and now want to compare it with clahe and s curve transformation. But the output of s curve is not an improved version of the original image as expected. Also, in clahe the command adapthisteq is not working and shows errors. Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

## Applying S-Curve/Contrast Stretching

This question seems to come up a lot so I’ve created a few example scripts. The first step in this method involves normalizing the images to constrain the intensities from 0 to 1. With the intensities ranging from 0 to 1, 0.5 can now be considered the mid-intensity. Typically, S-curve transforms can be described by a piecewise function containing two specific regions, a region that pulls up the intensities and another complementary region that pulls down the intensities. The below image and equations outline properties used to configure the transform curves:

[image: Contrast Stretching Properties]

---

[image: Contrast Stretched Results]

### Method 1: Using Condition on Image Matrix

This method using a conditional statement to access the indices of the image matrix/array and transform them accordingly.

```
Image = rgb2gray(imread("saturn.png"));
Alpha = 5;

subplot(1,2,1); imshow(Image);
title("Original Image");

%Normalizing image from intensities 0 to 1%
Image = im2double(Image);

%Grabbing image size and pre-allocated array to hold contrast stretched
%image%
[Image_Height,Image_Width,~] = size(Image);
Contrast_Stretched_Image = zeros(Image_Height,Image_Width);

Contrast_Stretched_Image(Image < 0.5) = 0.5.*((Image(Image < 0.5)./0.5).^Alpha);
Contrast_Stretched_Image(Image >= 0.5) = 1 - (0.5.*(((1-Image(Image >= 0.5))./0.5).^Alpha));
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(Contrast_Stretched_Image);
title("Contrast Stretched Image");
```

---

### Method 2: Using For-Loops

This method uses a set of for-loops to traverse through the pixels and evaluate a set of if-statements that correspond to the piecewise transform function.

```
Image = rgb2gray(imread("saturn.png"));
Alpha = 5;

subplot(1,2,1); imshow(Image);
title("Original Image");

%Normalizing image from intensities 0 to 1%
Image = im2double(Image);

%Grabbing image size and pre-allocated array to hold contrast stretched
%image%
[Image_Height,Image_Width,~] = size(Image);
Contrast_Stretched_Image = zeros(Image_Height,Image_Width);

for Row = 1: Image_Height
    for Column = 1: Image_Width

    Pixel_Intensity = Image(Row,Column);
    if Pixel_Intensity < 0.5
        Contrast_Stretched_Image(Row,Column) = 0.5*((Pixel_Intensity/0.5)^Alpha);
    end

    if Pixel_Intensity >= 0.5
        Contrast_Stretched_Image(Row,Column) = 1 - (0.5*(((1-Pixel_Intensity)/0.5)^Alpha));
    end
        
    end
end

subplot(1,2,2); imshow(Contrast_Stretched_Image);
title("Contrast Stretched Image");
```

---

### Extension: Plotting Contrast Stretching Curves

```
clf;
Alpha = 5;
Image = (0: 0.01: 1);
[Image_Height,Image_Width,~] = size(Image);
Contrast_Stretched_Image = zeros(Image_Height,Image_Width);
Contrast_Stretched_Image(Image < 0.5) = 0.5.*((Image(Image < 0.5)./0.5).^Alpha);
Contrast_Stretched_Image(Image >= 0.5) = 1 - (0.5.*(((1-Image(Image >= 0.5))./0.5).^Alpha));
plot(Image,Contrast_Stretched_Image);
title("Contrast Stretched Image");
```